# Magento Qty Increments

Tags: magento

Basically all my products in magento are single units, however everything is sold in packs say 10 units to a pack. Theres the Enable Qty Increments on the product options in Magento and then you enter the Qty increments, which works without problems. However by default when you go to the product on the front end, hit add to cart it tries to add just 1 unit not the minimum of 10 is there a way, when you hit add to cart it adds the minimum qty of 10 rather than 1?

Comment: when you go to the checkout page ( after adding 1 to the cart ) does the price indicate 10 units or just 1?

Comment: in the qty field it displays 10 and the price reflects that

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a while after you posted the problem & you probably have a fix already..

We are looking at this problem ourselves.. & have an issue with Bundled products not allowing us to add more than one instance of the product on each page.. hard to explain..

What I am thinking to do is remove the quantity box from the actual product.. Customers can select in a drop down if they want packs of 5 - 10 - or singles.. if they require odd numbers they can adjust the number still in the checkout..

does that all make sense..

**Add to cart & Qty box are on the products.phtml page i think... I am still looking at all my options though.. Setting up a selection of Grouped products at the moment..**

*Just a passing suggestion ;)*

> Edit.. // What we have done as a final solution.. Use // Promotions /
>   Shopping Cart Rules.. You can make specific rules for Bulk categories
>   & Products in set numbers.. This will be a lot easier for our staff to
>   manage.. just drop requested products into a category called "bulk"
>   ..wish I had thought of it earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

In Admin panel go to 
`System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Product Stock Options` and set `Qty Increments` to what you want.

Comment: This will only add the pack restriction  (ie per 6 or per 12) - but not add the option to enter 1 as qty => resulting in 6 or 12 in the admin/order

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides Bundled Products to achieve such sell of products in packets.

Create a Bundle Product and follow these steps at Bundled Items tab in product edit form

1. Add New Option
2. Provide Title, select input type checkbox or multiselect and set Is Required to Yes
3. Search your product in below grid and add this product providing "Qty to add" to 10
4. Add selected product to option and then save product.

Comment: This does not work for configurable products where you would have to choose a size